# Finding the probability based on the given graph

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, graphical-model

I have a graph $G_1\rightarrow G_2\rightarrow G_3\rightarrow G_4$ which has random variables and it's probabilities are given by $$P(G_i=1|G_{i-1}=1)=a$$ $$P(G_i=1|G_{i-1}=0)=b$$ $$P(G_1=1)=a_0$$ I need to compute $P(G_1=1,G_2=0,G_3=1,G_4=0)$

I tried to solve this but I'm stuck here.

$P(G_1=1,G_2=0,G_3=1,G_4=0)=P(G_1=1|G_2=0)\cdot P(G_2=0|G_3=1)\cdot P(G_3=1|G_4=0)\cdot P(G_4=0)$

How can I get the values of $P(G_1=1|G_2=0)$ and $P(G_2=0|G_3=1)$ from the above table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Bayesian graph, the joint distribution can be written as
$$\begin{align}P(G_1=1,G_2=0,G_3=1,G_4=0)&=P(G_4=0|G_3=1)\times P(G_3=1|G_2=0)\\&\times P(G_2=0|G_1=1)P(G_1=1)\end{align}$$

You have all the necessary probabilities in your table.

Comment: No, if the given side is $1$ you either have $a$ or $1-a$. If the given side is $0$, it's $b$ or $1-b$.

Comment: For example, $P(G_4=0|G_3=1)=1-a$

Comment: That seems correct